# Vue - URL query params not showing

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am adding query params with Vue router `hash` mode.
config/

```
that.$router.push({ name: "confirmation", query: {type: "payment"} })
```

This works on my local like this.
`http://localhost:5000/#/confirmation?type=payment`

**On production I have loaded compiled Vue script on the site as front end app.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://[project].herokuapp.com/booking/assets/booking.js?"></script>
```

But query params are not showing.

```
https://[site]/pages/booking/#/confirmation
```

**expected**: `https://site/pages/booking/#/confirmation?type=payment`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is the production URL exact? Because it doesn't have a / before the #. Could've just been copied wrong but I want to make sure.

Comment: @JoshuaK98, yes. It was wrong. Updated.

Comment: are there any errors anywhere?

Comment: @JoshuaK98 just updated the post. Thank you!

Comment: If it's working in your local environment but not in production, then odds are there's either some kind of configuration issue for your production build, or it's possible that a bug is present in the minified JS that doesn't exist in the non-minified JS. Try using a production build in your local environment if possible to see if you can reproduce the issue. It should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: @B.Fleming, I have updated the post. Can you please check again for me?

Comment: @codermouse Unfortunately simply showing a generic `script` tag containing the format of your project file's inclusion into the page isn't really going to help us understand the problem any further. Unless you can provide any relevant console errors, show any differences in build configurations, or provide package versions, we don't really have much to go on. Please consider reading up on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can more effectively help you.